# Subdomain take over with github?

Tags: github, web, subdomain

I have a username on github "as my name is"  and also a subdomain like **otherusername.github.io** and on this Subdomain github error pages there, so I search on google and found that the subdomain is vulnerable to subdomain take over, now the big question is **How i claim on it?**.

**Is i create a repository on my profile with that name "otherusername.github.io? And that's all.**" If so then what do next?

I want to clear this doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a **[user page](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/)**

> You will need to name this repository with the account name.
>
> - You must use the username.github.io naming scheme.
> - Content from the master branch will be used to build and publish your GitHub Pages site.

That means you need an account with the right username (`otherusername`), and a repo named `otherusername.github.io`.

Comment: If that account name is already exits then? Is it still possible?

Comment: @UtkarshAgrawal Yes, it is possible. Simply try to create such an account: if you are denied, that will confirm it. But if it exists, it should be visible already under https://github.com/otherUsername